# Facebook Graph API Explorer is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-debugger

Suddenly my Facebook Developer Explorer is not working. It shows an empty body only with a header and footer.

I already clear the cache a few times, but nothing has changed. Here is the screenshot-

[image]

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: There have some issues from facebook side, I noticed in browser debug console says like:
ErrorUtils caught an error: "React reported an error from TypeError: this.refs.popover is undefined". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs`
May be facebook going to fix it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the older version is not working

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?classic=1

However, the new version loads

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?classic=0